# Receive DialogFragment result in BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: java, android

I have a BottomSheetDialogFragment that calls a DialogFragment and expect a result from it through the implementation of a listener.
I have set from the BottomSheetDialogFragment setTargetFragment(this, 0) method but I'm currently facing a "Wrong first argument type ... required android.app.Fragment".

```
import android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetDialogFragment;

public class MyBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    //...
    private void action(JSONObject item) {
        DialogFragment dialog = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(item);
        dialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
                              // ^^^^ Wrong first argument ... Required ... Fragment
        dialog.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), getTag());
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

MyDialogFragment file content

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;

public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(JSONObject payment_data) {
        return new MyDialogFragment();
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: have you tried explicitly casting the to Fragment such as `dialog.setTargetFragment( (Fragment) this, 0);` ? also, this assumes DialogFragment is extending Fragment class, which it should be

Comment: I will get an "InconvertibleTypes" issue if I try to cast it as suggested. And MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment. The class is located on a separate file.

Comment: What version of Fragment and DialogFragment are you using? maybe your using them from the wrong support library

Comment: I've just updated the code so you can have more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intention was to open a DialogFragment from a BottomSheetDialogFragment and get a result a bit like a callback.

Despite the fact that a [BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment.html) extends AppCompatDialogFragment that extends DialogFragment that extends Fragments, I wasn't able to "setTargetFragment" from BottomSheetDialogFragment. Therefore I decided to change the approach and to use [customs listeners](http://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-Custom-Listeners#custom-listeners). I'm now calling both my BottomSheetDialogFragment and DialogFragment directly from the MainActivity by listening to each of them.

Simple and it works as expected.